# Is an exact match necessary to prove trademark infringement?

Tags: united-states, trademark, civil-law, public-domain

For the sake of example, let's use Robert E. Howard's character "Conan, the Barbarian". The author died in June 11, 1936, Cross Plains, Texas, United States.

As seen above, it's been almost 97 years of his passing at the time this question was posted. His works, including the mentioned character, are well into public domain.

Though that might be true, the expression "Conan, the Barbarian" is trademarked. Assume I want to write a novel about the rebirth of the character in the modern times. The title would be "Conan, the reborn Barbarian".

Assume the copyright holder sues me for infringement of the eponymous copyright. Do they have cause to file this lawsuit?

Does the use in the hypothetical above constitute a "sufficiently related" use as stated in https://www.uspto.gov/page/about-trademark-infringement

> The key factors considered in most cases are the degree of similarity between the marks at issue and whether the parties' goods and/or services are sufficiently related that consumers are likely to assume (mistakenly) that they come from a common source. Other factors that courts typically consider include how and where the parties' goods or services are advertised, marketed, and sold; the purchasing conditions; the range of prospective purchasers of the goods or services; whether there is any evidence of actual confusion caused by the allegedly infringing mark; the defendant's intent in adopting its mark; and the strength of the plaintiff's mark.

Issues of [copyright](/questions/tagged/copyright) are to be ignored. There's no copyrighted material or fair use. The character used in the hypothetical is in [public-domain](/questions/tagged/public-domain).

Comment: When you said "Assume the copyright holder sues me for infringement of the eponymous copyright", did you intend "Assume the trademark holder sues me for infringement of the eponymous trademark"?

Comment: Related: [Supreme Court sides with Jack Daniels in trademark fight over poop-themed dog toy](https://www.cbsnews.com/colorado/news/supreme-court-jack-daniels-vip-products-dog-toy-trademark/?intcid=CNM-00-10abd1h)

Answer (score 2):

An exact match to a trademark is not necessary for trademark infringement to occur, as demonstrated in Toys "R" Us v. Akkaoui, 40 U.S.P.Q.2d (BNA) 1836 (N.D. Cal. 1996). Toys R Us successfully sued the adult website Adults R Us despite the lack of an exact match to any trademark, as the use of the name "Adults R Us" diluted the trademark of Toys R Us.

However, your specific hypothetical would probably need an actual lawyer to properly guess whether it would likely be considered infringing, as it's hard to know for certain.

Comment: The correct legal standard is "confusingly similar."